# Typo3 extbase include html2pdf

Tags: typo3, extbase, html2pdf

How to include html2pdf in extbase v6.1 extension ?

I am writing an extension, there I need to convert created field information to pdf with nice table structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the problem?! In the documentation of [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/de/example) there are different examples. You could write a PDFController and trigger this controller with a typenum and special headercode.

```
pdf = PAGE
pdf {
    typeNum = 300
    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
        pluginName = PLUGINNAME
        extensionName = EXTENSIONNAME
        controller = Pdf
        action = html2pdf
        switchableControllerActions {
            Pdf {
                1 = html2pdf
            }
        }
        settings =< plugin.tx_yourext.settings
        persistence =< plugin.tx_yourext.persistence
        view =< plugin.tx_yourext.view
    }
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/pdf
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
    }
}
```